# Cannot Enter Credentials Over UAC Prompts During Remote Assistance

Tags: windows, sonicwall, remote-desktop

We are using SonicWALL firewall devices throughout our network. We use the SonicWALL Virtual Assistance tool for remote desktop assistance. Since our systems are not in a workgroup and are on a domain, we face problems when the UAC prompts appear.

As a workaround, we edited the UAC policies such as switching to secure desktop-disable, Allowing UI Acess applications to prompt for elevation without using secure desktop-Enable, etc. The ultimate result was we are able to see the UAC prompt on the remote user system, but we are not able to interact with it and are not able to enter credentials to it.  I can see the password being entered if it is done by the local user. However, we cannot interact with the UAC prompt window remotely. Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use SCCM. When using remote tools in SCCM you can type in the UAC prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling the following group policy option on workstation computers may allow you to remotely interact with UAC prompts. This is needed for Microsoft's built-in remote assistance facilities.

`Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Security Options\User Account Control: Allow UIAccess applications to prompt for elevation without using the secure desktop`

Answer (score 0):

No there is no solution for this. This is the intention of the UAC dialog that there is no interaction possible. So malicious code or malicious people can't run any code as administrator.